# Pgfplots: plot graph inside table

Tags: tables, pgfplots, plot

I would like to plot a table with a graph inside it. I am trying to use [this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/weather-stations-data/) as a guide. This is the current hand-constructed version.

[image: 1]

**UPDATE:** I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question, but I'm getting there:

I have got this far, using `\multirow`
So with a little tweaking I may be able to get it to work? I will come back and edit if I do.

[image: attempt]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\errplot}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}%[xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5, ymin=-.5,ymax=23,grid=both] 
\addplot+[only marks][error bars/.cd,x dir=both, x explicit]
coordinates {
(-0.42,22)+-(0.86,-1.7)
(0.04,21)+-(0.9,-0.81)
(0.1,20)+-(0.69,-0.49)
(0.3,19)+-(0.7,-0.1)
(0.8,18)+-(0.72,0.88)
(0.37,17)+-(0.7,0.04)
(-0.03,16)+-(0.68,-0.75)
(-0.3,15)+-(0.53,-1.13)
(0.32,14)+-(0.54,0.1)
(-0.38,13)+-(0.55,-1.31)
(0.12,12)+-(0.54,-0.3)
(-0.1,11)+-(0.53,-0.73)
(0.12,10)+-(0.55,-0.32)
(-0.2,9)+-(0.57,-0.97)
(-0.39,8)+-(0.58,-1.36)
(-0.35,7)+-(0.57,-1.27)
(0.09,6)+-(0.56,-0.37)
(-0.53,5)+-(0.55,-1.62)
(0.23,4)+-(0.56,-0.11)
(0.18,3)+-(0.58,-0.21)
(0.05,2)+-(0.57,-0.47)
(0.02,1)+-(0.55,-0.52)
};
\addplot[dashed] coordinates {(0,-1) (0,24)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering                          
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c}           
\hline
& & & & Standardised \\ 
& & z & \emph{p} & Mean (95\% CI) \\ [0.5ex]  
\hline
Afear & \multirow{22}{8cm}{\errplot} & -0.96 & 0.33 & -0.42 (-1.28 to 0.44) \\
Anofear & & 0.09 & 0.93 & 0.04 (-0.85 to 0.94) \\
B+2 & & 0.29 & 0.78 & 0.10 (-0.59 to 0.79) \\
B+1 & & 0.84 & 0.40 & 0.30 (-0.40 to 1.00) \\
B1:1 & & 2.19 & 0.03 & 0.80 (0.08 to 1.52) \\
B-1 & & 1.02 & 0.31 & 0.37 (-0.33 to 1.07) \\
B-2 & & -0.10 & 0.92 & -0.03 (-0.72 to 0.65) \\
C+2 & & -1.11 & 0.27 & -0.30 (-0.83 to 0.23) \\
C+1 & & 1.15 &  0.25 & 0.32 (-0.22 to 0.86) \\
C1:1 & & -1.34 & 0.18 & -0.38 (-0.93 to 0.17) \\
C-1 & & 0.43 & 0.67 & 0.12 (-0.42 to 0.66) \\
C-2 & & -0.37 & 0.71 & -0.10 (-0.63 to 0.43) \\
D+2 & & 0.41 & 0.68 & 0.12 (-0.44 to 0.67) \\
D+1 & & -0.69 & 0.49 & -0.20 (-0.77 to 0.37) \\
D1:1 & & -1.33 & 0.18 & -0.39 (-0.97 to 0.19) \\
D-1 & & -1.21 & 0.23 & -0.35 (-0.92 to 0.22) \\
D-2 & & 0.32 & 0.75 & 0.09 (-0.46 to 0.65) \\
E+2 & & -1.89 & 0.06 & -0.53 (-1.09 to 0.02) \\
E+1 & & 0.78 & 0.44 & 0.23 (-0.34 to 0.79) \\
E1:1 & & 0.62 & 0.53 & 0.18 (-0.39 to 0.76) \\
E-1 & & 0.17 & 0.86 & 0.05 (-0.52 to 0.62) \\
E-2 & & 0.06 & 0.95 & 0.02 (-0.54 to 0.57) \\ [1ex]        
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


%\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Good idea!

If you set `y=\baselineskip` for the `axis` environment, you'll get the right spacing. Instead of drawing the vertical dashed line as a plot, you should set `axis y line*=middle, y axis line style=dashed, ytick=\empty` to get a dashed axis without ticks. Fiddling with the limits and the top and bottom row heights a bit, setting `axis y line=none, axis x line*=bottom` and using proper `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` as provided by `booktabs` leads to the following:

[image: pgfplots inside table]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\errplot}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[y=\baselineskip,
  ymax=22.4,
  ymin=0,
  axis y line*=middle,
  y axis line style=dashed,
  ytick=\empty,
  axis x line*=bottom]
\addplot+[only marks][error bars/.cd,x dir=both, x explicit]
coordinates {
(-0.42,22)+-(0.86,-1.7)
(0.04,21)+-(0.9,-0.81)
(0.1,20)+-(0.69,-0.49)
(0.3,19)+-(0.7,-0.1)
(0.8,18)+-(0.72,0.88)
(0.37,17)+-(0.7,0.04)
(-0.03,16)+-(0.68,-0.75)
(-0.3,15)+-(0.53,-1.13)
(0.32,14)+-(0.54,0.1)
(-0.38,13)+-(0.55,-1.31)
(0.12,12)+-(0.54,-0.3)
(-0.1,11)+-(0.53,-0.73)
(0.12,10)+-(0.55,-0.32)
(-0.2,9)+-(0.57,-0.97)
(-0.39,8)+-(0.58,-1.36)
(-0.35,7)+-(0.57,-1.27)
(0.09,6)+-(0.56,-0.37)
(-0.53,5)+-(0.55,-1.62)
(0.23,4)+-(0.56,-0.11)
(0.18,3)+-(0.58,-0.21)
(0.05,2)+-(0.57,-0.47)
(0.02,1)+-(0.55,-0.52)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering                          
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c}           
\toprule
& & & & Standardised \\ 
& & z & \emph{p} & Mean (95\% CI) \\
\midrule
Afear & \multirow{22}{7cm}{\errplot} & -0.96 & 0.33 & -0.42 (-1.28 to 0.44) \\
Anofear & & 0.09 & 0.93 & 0.04 (-0.85 to 0.94) \\
B+2 & & 0.29 & 0.78 & 0.10 (-0.59 to 0.79) \\
B+1 & & 0.84 & 0.40 & 0.30 (-0.40 to 1.00) \\
B1:1 & & 2.19 & 0.03 & 0.80 (0.08 to 1.52) \\
B-1 & & 1.02 & 0.31 & 0.37 (-0.33 to 1.07) \\
B-2 & & -0.10 & 0.92 & -0.03 (-0.72 to 0.65) \\
C+2 & & -1.11 & 0.27 & -0.30 (-0.83 to 0.23) \\
C+1 & & 1.15 &  0.25 & 0.32 (-0.22 to 0.86) \\
C1:1 & & -1.34 & 0.18 & -0.38 (-0.93 to 0.17) \\
C-1 & & 0.43 & 0.67 & 0.12 (-0.42 to 0.66) \\
C-2 & & -0.37 & 0.71 & -0.10 (-0.63 to 0.43) \\
D+2 & & 0.41 & 0.68 & 0.12 (-0.44 to 0.67) \\
D+1 & & -0.69 & 0.49 & -0.20 (-0.77 to 0.37) \\
D1:1 & & -1.33 & 0.18 & -0.39 (-0.97 to 0.19) \\
D-1 & & -1.21 & 0.23 & -0.35 (-0.92 to 0.22) \\
D-2 & & 0.32 & 0.75 & 0.09 (-0.46 to 0.65) \\
E+2 & & -1.89 & 0.06 & -0.53 (-1.09 to 0.02) \\
E+1 & & 0.78 & 0.44 & 0.23 (-0.34 to 0.79) \\
E1:1 & & 0.62 & 0.53 & 0.18 (-0.39 to 0.76) \\
E-1 & & 0.17 & 0.86 & 0.05 (-0.52 to 0.62) \\
E-2 & & 0.06 & 0.95 & 0.02 (-0.54 to 0.57) \\[4ex]        
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Addition:** Because it's painful to do something like this in a static way, here's an approach that reads the data from a datafile with `pgfplotstable` and typesets the table and the plot dynamically. The example uses the `filecontents` environment to write the datafile, this wouldn't be necessary in a real application:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% The data file
\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
name z p mean lci uci
Afear -0.96  0.33 -0.42 -1.28 0.44
Anofear 0.09 0.93 0.04 -0.85 0.94
B+2 0.29 0.78 0.10 -0.59 0.79
B+1   0.84  0.40  0.30 -0.40 1.00 
B1:1   2.19  0.03  0.80 0.08 1.52 
B-1   1.02  0.31  0.37 -0.33 1.07 
B-2   -0.10  0.92  -0.03 -0.72 0.65 
C+2   -1.11  0.27  -0.30 -0.83 0.23 
C+1   1.15   0.25  0.32 -0.22 0.86 
C1:1   -1.34  0.18  -0.38 -0.93 0.17 
C-1   0.43  0.67  0.12 -0.42 0.66 
C-2   -0.37  0.71  -0.10 -0.63 0.43 
D+2   0.41  0.68  0.12 -0.44 0.67 
D+1   -0.69  0.49  -0.20 -0.77 0.37 
D1:1   -1.33  0.18  -0.39 -0.97 0.19 
D-1   -1.21  0.23  -0.35 -0.92 0.22 
D-2   0.32  0.75  0.09 -0.46 0.65 
E+2   -1.89  0.06  -0.53 -1.09 0.02 
E+1   0.78  0.44  0.23 -0.34 0.79 
E1:1   0.62  0.53  0.18 -0.39 0.76 
E-1   0.17  0.86  0.05 -0.52 0.62 
E-2   0.06  0.95  0.02 -0.54 0.57
\end{filecontents}

% Read data file, create new column ``upper CI boundary - mean''
\pgfplotstableread{data.txt}\data
\pgfplotstableset{create on use/error/.style={
    create col/expr={\thisrow{uci}-\thisrow{mean}
    }
  }
}

% Define the command for the plot
\newcommand{\errplot}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[y=-\baselineskip,
  scale only axis,
  width=6.5cm,
  enlarge y limits={abs=0.5},
  axis y line*=middle,
  y axis line style=dashed,
  ytick=\empty,
  axis x line*=bottom]
% 
% ``mean'' must be present in the datafile, ``error'' is the newly generated column
\addplot+[only marks][error bars/.cd,x dir=both, x explicit]
table [x=mean,y expr=\coordindex,x error=error]{\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

% Get number of rows in datafile
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\data}
\let\numberofrows=\pgfplotsretval

% Print the table
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={name,error,z,p,mean,ci},
  % Booktabs rules
  every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=[3ex]\bottomrule},
  % Set header name
  columns/name/.style={string type,column name=Name},
  % Use the ``error'' column to call the \errplot command in a multirow cell in the first row, keep empty for all other rows
  columns/error/.style={
    column name={},
    assign cell content/.code={% use \multirow for Z column:
    \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=0
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}
    {\multirow{\numberofrows}{6.5cm}{\errplot}}%
    \else
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
    \fi
    }
  },
  % Format numbers and titles
  columns/mean/.style={column name=Mean,fixed,fixed zerofill,dec sep align},
  columns/z/.style={column name=$z$,fixed,fixed zerofill,dec sep align},
  columns/p/.style={column name=$p$,fixed,fixed zerofill,dec sep align},
  columns/ci/.style={string type,column name=95\% CI},
  % Create the ``(x to y)'' format, use \pgfmathprintnumber with `showpos` to make things align nicely
  create on use/ci/.style={
    create col/assign/.code={\edef\value{(
    \noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[showpos,fixed,fixed zerofill]{\thisrow{lci}} to \noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[showpos,fixed,fixed zerofill]{\thisrow{uci}})}
      \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\value
    }
  }
]{\data}
%Done!
\end{document}
```

[image: dynamic way to typeset table and graph of a data set]

Comment: Fantastic. Beat me to it. And it looks beautiful. Many thanks.

Comment: For some reason I can't compile your second version. I get lots of undefined control sequences etc. Very nice though.

Comment: @RSoul: Ah, I feared so, sorry. I guess this uses a couple of features that are only available in the development version of PGFplots.

Comment: Ah okay. Good to know.